# Download Jupyter Notebook as PDF MikteX problem

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, miktex

I'm getting "500: Internal Server Error" and the error messages below when I try to download a jupyter notebook as a pdf.  Does anyone see what the issue might be?  I've installed nbconvert, pandoc, and miktex.  I'm working on a windows 10 machine with python 3.6.

Errors:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
xelatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6730)
entering extended mode
(notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\base\size11.clo))
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\base\fontenc.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\base\t1enc.def)
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\lm\t1lmr.fd))
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\psnfss\mathpazo.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\graphics-def\xetex.def)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\lat
ex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\gen
eric\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\tex\gen
eric\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox.st
y)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-xetex.def))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty)

======================================================================

Sorry, but C:\Users\username\AppDataPython\envs\py36\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\xelatex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/xelatex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

Comment: Did you figure this problem out?  I'm having the same issue

Comment: @getaglow the work around I came up with was to hit ctrl+P in chrome to open up the print window then change the source to save as pdf and just save it that way.  This is the second time I've tried to fix the whole nb_convert/latex issue, once on windows once on mac, both times I wound up doing a work around.  On mac you can open in safari and download as pdf.

Comment: thanks.  I've resorted to exporting to latex and then opening the document up in Miktex and then converting to pdf.  If I figure it out, I'll send it your way.